# Disappearing/ unavailable delimited text layers each time i close and re-open a project

Tags: qgis, vector-layer

I am adding drillhole locations to a map via 'add delimited text layer'. I add the points to the project ok and save. The points appear in the right place and i can edit them. However, on closing the project and reopening i get:
[image]

I .txt layer that i'm loading hasn't changed location and there has been no changes to the folder structure at all.

Why does it keep having problems finding this layer every time?

Comment: Do you open it from the File::open dialog or by double clicking on the project? Although relative paths are a good idea if they aren't working then perhaps, if only for this layer, add it using the full path; you might need to add the layer via your UNC path (\\%ComputerName%\) to force the issue.

Comment: Perhaps this question and answers might help. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427340/inconsistent-error-opening-tab-delimited-text-files This concerns importing "text" files which are in fact delimited using TAB characters, but which Excel in its wisdom writes with the suffix "txt". Note the short-term plugin referred to, which overcomes the problem.

Comment: i just updated to 3.30 hertogenbosch and now no longer seem to get the recurring problem. Not sure how it solved  it but it appears to have done so.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems in your approach:

1. The file you load seems to be a txt file, not a csv file. You should save your text file as csv.
2. You say you "added delimited text layer" to QGIS. CSV files cannot be edited in QGIS and changes will not be saved. Load your CSV to QGIS, than export/save it to a Geopackage. On this layer, you can make changes that will be preserved.

Comment: Are csv somehow inherently better than bringing in points as .txt? Or just in this instance it might have solved the problem (were it not for the update seemingly solving the problem)

Comment: The import is made for "Delimited text", thus csv (comma separated values), not for txt files. csv format is always structured, txt can also contain unstructured text.

Comment: @Babel you make the good point that many ".txt" files are unstructured and therefore not suitable for "delimited text" import. By contrast, a tab-delimited text file is readily imported as a delimited file, but by default Excel names these as ".txt" files.

Comment: Ah yes Leigh, that's what I had sorry for the confusion. Mine were tab-delimited on looking at it but I've always just looked at the .txt